# Python method coding: is a local name referring to an attribute ok to avoid repeating self.attribute?

Tags: python, attributes, coding-style, self

Imagine you have a very important attribute in a Python class, so that a method will refer to it many times. For example,

```
class BeautifulDiagram(Object)
   def draw(self):
        # c is the drawing canvas (ReportLab), we use it many times
        self.c.setLineWidth(0.5 * mm)
        self.c.setStrokeColor('grey')
        ....
```

Would it be good practice - or not- to avoid writing plenty of attribute self.c in the exemple above, by creating a local reference to it, such as

```
   c = self.c
   c.setLineWidth(0.5 * mm)
   c.setStrokeColor('grey')
```

Is there any reason to avoid that (afaik, it works), either because it is against coding guidelines or inefficient (I don't think it is a big burden given that it only copies references to attributes)?
Is anything else better practice?

Comment: What you have is fine. However, the Zen of Python suggests explicit is better than implicit. Also, beware that you may be tempted later in the method to do `c = <new canvas>` which would not work. You *have* to do `self.c = <new canvas>`.

Comment: Thanks. I entirely understand that c = <new canvas> would not be appropriate, as it would just set a variable c as referring to a new object, without changing the one it was previously referring to. So being Zen in Python means repeating quite a lot of self.something?

Comment: You can always apply the [Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) of [Demeter](https://wiki.c2.com/?LawOfDemeter) and have `def setupCanvas(self, c): c.setLine...`

Comment: Could someone tell me why the question is now rated  "-1" ? Who decided that it is "not useful" ? If it stays like that, I'll just delete it, but I though that the question and potential answers were useful (although the first comment at least would benefit from being posted as answer, given that comments are not intended to provide answers).

Comment: Technically this question is off-topic since it is asking for opinions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is fine. However, the Zen of Python suggests explicit is better than implicit, so you'll find that the style of your first snippet is quite common.

Also, beware in your second snippet that you may be tempted later in the method to do `c = <new canvas>` which would not work. You have to do `self.c = <new canvas>`

There is another option which is to apply the [Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) of [Demeter](https://wiki.c2.com/?LawOfDemeter) and have:

```py
    def draw(self):
        self.setupCanvas(self.c)

    def setupCanvas(self, c): 
       c.setLineWidth(0.5 * mm)
       c.setStrokeColor('grey')
       ...
```